# Make iis7 accessible from the internet

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista

How can i Make iis7 accessible from the internet ? i opened port 80 on my router and firewall but i use try to access it i get the router configuration . any ideas ??

Comment: See my edit below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the router 'management port' from 80 to something else, 8080 for example. Another option may be to 'disable management from the internet' on the router. Without knowing the exact model of router you have it is dificult to give exact instructions.

Edit:

I could only find the manual for the 3302 model, and its in French. There's a section in the middle of the manual which talks about accessing the router from the internet, but I cant make out weather it says you can or cant change the port from 80 to something else ( my french is very rusty). Anyway, heres a [link](http://support.sagem-communications.com/site/livret/288072168-01.pdf) to the manual for someone with better French than mine to help you.

Comment: I have a sagem F@st3304

Comment: My french is very good where can i find he manual ?

Comment: See the 'link' in  my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the "Port Forwarding" setting in your router, set port 80 to forward to your pc's ip address that has IIS installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

other then do port forwarding, keep in mind that a lot of ISPs for home based users won't allow port 80 to go in, so try alternative port instead

Answer (score 1):

Your router is configured to allow web based management from the internet. You need to turn this off. you do not need to change the port that the web based management runs on. Most, if not all, modern SOHO routers allow web based management from the internal network as well as from the internet. Turn off the option for web based management from the internet.